# DigitalOcean connect node.js to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

I created and deployed a `MERN` web app on `DigitalOcean` which works fine using a Mongo database hosted on `mlab.com`, but now I want to host the database on `DigitalOcean` and I'm having difficulties with this...

I followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04 but now I don't know how to connect my node.js server to this database.

Does the connection to `127.0.0.1:27017/mydbname` should work on production?

Any solution or advice would help me a lot.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is an IP of the droplet you are connecting from. If your app and your database are on different droplets you need to use IP of the droplet where database is running. You may want to use private network to secure the connection, but it is quite broad question, is off topic here, and very likely was already answered few times.

Comment: Accessing droppletIP:27017 in a browser tab should display something?

Comment: No, of course not. It doesn't speak http. You can connect to `droppletIP:27017` from your mongodb client, if the server is configured to listen on public interface. It is not recommended tho.

Comment: @AlexBlex to use private network I simply have to check the "Private networking" checkbox when creating a new droplet and then get the ip address using ifconfig?

Comment: The private networking is very well described at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-digitalocean-private-networking and the best place to ask about it is https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @valip, did you win with this issue?

Comment: @jae.phoenix not really...I can't get make the connection from node.js to the hosted db on digital ocean